# Angular and vanila JS - set input value

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to set input value (in Vanilla JS)  in website created in Agnular.

when I try to do:

```
document.querySelector('my_input').value = 'value';
```

the value shows in input but searching doesn't see this value (form is submitted but it looks like my input is empty).

I see that there is event ngModelChange.

Is there any option to do something like that:

```
document.querySelector('my_input').dispatchEvent(new Event('ngModelChange', {value: 'value'}));
```

If I do that i get in input [object Event] and the form searching get this value.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Moreover, why not use what angular has to provide as you are using angular? if you want to set a value to an input... use ngModel.

Comment: It's kind of complicated. I don't have access to source of this angular application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my problem.
This code works for me:

```
document.querySelector('my_input').value = 'my_value';
document.querySelector('my_input').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
document.querySelector('my_input').dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));
```

Thanks for you answers.

Comment: Just dispatching input event worked for me. Any reason for dispatching blur event?